# Looking for a configurable autocomplete jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm looking for an automcomplete jquery plugin that will let me pick suggestions (with image capability) when I type the letter @. The textbox can contain other text too, so not just the list of suggestions.

Something like this: http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/ however, I don't need the fancy removable blocks.  Plus, I need to be able to type text other than what is suggested.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jquery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) is all you need.

It allows you to use various events to hook in your own code for responding and loading, etc.

Comment: Some of the other plugins I saw had a feature where when you put focus on the textbox, a little panel drops down saying "Start typing a letter..." Can this be done with jquery UI autocomplete?  I don't see any option to turn that on.

Comment: No this does not do it for you.